# # of partitions written to disk when writing a dataframe to a csv file using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a data frame with `10` partitions into a CSV file in spark. After the write operation is over, I see only `4` files written inside the folder which I give in the option method.

But as per the concept, all the partitions should be written into individual files even when they are empty. Below is the code I use:

```
//partitionedDataFromMySql is already available
Console println  "Number of partitions are: " + partitionedDataFromMySql.rdd.getNumPartitions  //prints 10
partitionedDataFromMySql.write.format("csv").option("path","E:\\xxxx\\spark\\example").save
```

Can someone please help me why there are lesser number of partitions. I don't reduce the number of partitions of the dataframe anywhere in my code.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the spark version you're using? I've tried it with 2.4.3 and it creates 10 files.

Comment: I am using 2.2.4 version of spark. Thanks!